# Deploying Seq on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, serilog, seq-logging

I'm trying to Deploy Seq by Datalust on IIS and I'm getting this error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure
```

here is the error in windows event viewer

```
Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x8007023e'.
```

here is the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\Seq.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

the official documents are only available for deployment on Azure using Docker image or self hosted Kestrel application. Is my approach possible?

Comment: A quick report should tell if common issues are there, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html You might also find more information about those common issues on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-iis-errors-reference?view=aspnetcore-3.1#incorrect-processpath-missing-path-variable-hosting-bundle-not-installed-systemiis-not-restarted-vc-redistributable-not-installed-or-dotnetexe-access-violation

Answer (score 1):

Seq's Windows hosting infrastructure uses `HTTP.sys` and not the ASP.NET Core/IIS integration, so this is not possible as far as we know, today.

IIS can be used as a reverse proxy in front of Seq, however, which covers some of the scenarios in which you might want to do this.